# Running a bash script from an xsession to toggle startup programs

Tags: bash, 16.04, lightdm, sh

So I've got an interesting challenge in front of me, running Ubuntu 16.04.

I originally created a .xsession file that ran `Exec=google-chrome --kiosk http://some-url.com` to boot as a kiosk device.

The above mentioned .xsession file exists in `/usr/share/xsessions/`, and is set to the default session in the lightdm config file found at `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.d.conf/50-ubuntu.conf`.

That worked just fine.

### On to the new challenge:

I want to be able to remotely toggle whether or not the device boots in kiosk mode.

In an attempt to do this I have modified the Exec command to run a bash script that I've written to determine whether or not to boot as a kiosk.

The following script is executed from the .xsession file:

```
#! /bin/bash

KIOSK_MODE=$(curl http://some-url.com/bootInKioskMode/)

if [ $KIOSK_MODE = "true" ] ; then
    google-chrome --kiosk http://some-url.com
else
    gnome-session --session=ubuntu &
    unity
fi
```

The idea is that because I can control what http://some-url.com/bootInKioskMode/ returns, I should be able to toggle what mode the device boots into

As it stands now, I have two problems that I need to solve.

1. My if/else statement is always matching false...so it is not booting into kiosk mode even if the curl response is `true`.
2. When it boots and runs the commands after the `else` statement, it doesn't really match a default boot. The top menu bar is missing, as well as the icons and settings options on the top right of the screen.

**Other things worth mentioning:**

- I do know that it is connected to the internet, and the curl request is firing off ok through testing (having it output and save to a file).
- I have it setup to auto-login to a kiosk user that does not have sudo permissions, and have been running tests in these conditions.

---

Any help with this is appreciated. At this point I've spent hours googling and trying out different things and I've yet to have much luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-decompose your problem. You could easily write a simple Perl script to listen to an agreed-upon port (e.g. `30201`) See [this example from thegeekstuff.com](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/perl-tcp-udp-socket-programming/). Have the server part accept 3 commands: "kiosk", "desktop" and "quit". "kiosk" and "desktop" set/clear a flag like `/var/run/kiosk-mode`. Start the server in `/etc/init`. Then you can simply `if [[ -f /var/run/kiosk-mode ]] ; then ...` in your script.